# CakePHP 3.1 admin prefix routing and logging in issue

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm starting a new app using Cake 3.1 for the first time. I used to use version 2+, but now things have changed and I am encountering some troubles.

I want to have a simple authorization system in my app, so I decide to go with "admin" prefix routing.

I have:
UsersController with **login** action, '**ArticlesController**' with namespace **App\Controller\Admin** in **Controller/Admin/** directory.

In routes.php I have:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
$routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

What goes wrong:
If I have already logged in everything works fine and I have access to my admin actions.
But if I'm **not** logged in, and will try to access /admin/articles/add I will be redirected to  /**admin**/users/login. And this is totally wrong and I'm obviously get *Missing Controller exception*.

My question:
What I need to do to fix this and get a proper redirect to **login** action /users/login and not the prefixed version (/**admin**/users/login).

**AppController**:

```
    public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home',
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ]
    ]);
}
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'display']);
}
```

Comment: Please also show your auth component configuration/calls that the `ArticlesController` is subject to.

Comment: @ndm I've updated my post. I'm just starting this project, so this entire code that I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. I found the solution – just need to add

```
    'loginAction' => [
    'prefix' => false,
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'login',
    ]
```

to auth component configuration